# Get values between tags and convert them as link

Tags: php, substr

I have a site where I would like to get a value from textarea on submit and replace it wih a link, e.g. a user submitted `Hello @testuser how are you?`

I want to get the content between `@` and space and replace it with

`<a href="user.php?name=testuser">testuser</a>`

I searched for it a lot but couldn't find anything to work with. I also did it without dynamic content. The script is:

```
<?php
$tagOne = "[";
$tagTwo = "]";

$text = "Hello, my name is [lol]";
$uname = "lol";
$replacement = "<a href=\"dash.php?page=account&name=".$uname."\">".$uname."</a>";

$startTagPos = strrpos($text, $tagOne);
$endTagPos = strrpos($text, $tagTwo);
$tagLength = $endTagPos - $startTagPos + 1;

$text = substr_replace($text, $replacement, $startTagPos, $tagLength);

echo $text;
?>
```

This is perfect if I only have a username defined in the code but not the user. I want the same result but dynamically.

Comment: If you're asking how to access data from a form, there's a tutorial here: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php

Comment: Yes, duplicate. Sorry. I couldn't find it before! Thank you @k0pernikus. :)

Comment: @MLL Nothing to be sorry about. Duplicates can be helpful as they direct other users to the right questions due to different phrasing. It's only bad if you haven't searched at all beforehand ;)

Comment: Not exact duplicate. With that solution in my script there is a `@` in the link and username. I don't want that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a database, make a users table,
 then connect to the database in the file you're working with, and query out the user based on the id and assign it to a variable ex.($username). 
 Then you can replace the "my name is '[lol]' " to "my name is '$username' ". 
 I suppose this would work, if i understood your question right.

Comment: hm.Not really. I don't care if the user exists or not. I used 
`<?php
$comment = "Hello @lol how are you?";
$post = preg_replace('/(@\w+)/', '<a href=\'dash.php?page=account&name=\1\'>\1</a>', $comment);
echo $post;
?>` 
but there is the `@` in the name and also the link. How to remove it?

Comment: $p = str_replace("(@)", "", $value); echo $p; have you tried this, just to see if it works?

Comment: It works for me without () tags. Anyway, thank you very much :)